# Do all players need to own Age of Mythology in Steam to play multiplayer online?

Tags: steam, age-of-mythology

A friend of mine owns Age of Mythology through Steam. I don’t own it but I have a Steam account. Can I play Age of Mythology over the Internet with him since one of us owns it? Or do I need to purchase it too?

Comment: You can always play steam in offline mode and do a LAN game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each player will need to own a copy to play together.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the Steam version is [incompatible](https://steamcommunity.com/app/266840/discussions/0/541906989391862380/) with the original 2002 release version as well.